# How to install a plugin to PhoneGap project

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new in phonegap. I read other topics but need more help.
I want to add ads to my project from appodeal ad network. they said:

To install Appodeal PhoneGap Plugin to your project add following to your config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.appodeal.plugin"  />
```

I don't use phonegap build so I can't use this way. Can you explain what should I do? and get me a example. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PhoneGap with command interface then simply run:

```
cordova plugin add com.appodeal.plugin
```

if not, then give us some additional info, like how you are using PhoneGap.